# Using C/C++ in VS Code, how can I create lists and tables within tooltip description of symbols?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, tooltip, documentation

I'm using VS Code to program in C language.
C/C++ extension gives you ability to create description, documentation and shows it when you hover your mouse over the symbol.

```c
    /**
     * @brief General control register
     *
     * @param b15 Reserved
     * @param b14 Disable TXA output and set to high impedance
     * @param b13 Disable TXAN output and set to high impedance
     * @param b12 Xtal frequency: 0 = 12.2880 MHz, 1 = 11.0592 MHz
     * @param b11 Analog loopdown. When used, tx/rx mode settings must be same
     * @param b10 Disable TX/RX fixed compromise equalizer
     * @param b9 Relay drive(RDRVN) output: 0 = VDD, 1 = VSS
     * @param b8 Power up: 0 = power save mode, 1 = normal mode
     * @param b7 Reset. On power on, reset and power up must be set to 1 and wait for at least 20 ms
     * @param b6 Enable nIRQ according to status register
     * @param b5-b0 IRQ mask bits
     * 
     */
    uint16_t generalControl;
```

[image: How description works]

Currently I'm using `@param` for each bit description but I'd prefer lists(and tables for future use). I wonder if it is possible to do such thing in vscode c.

Here are some things I tried but didn't work.

```c
    /**
     * @brief Transmit mode register
     * 
     * @param b15-b12 TX mode
     * 
     * 
     * - Is list working?
     * -# List item 1
     * -# I don't think so
     * 
     * <table>
     * <tr><td>0000</td><td>Normal mode</td></tr>
     * </table>
     * 
     */
    uint16_t transmitMode;
```

[image: Failed to add list and table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this will be supported once the VS Code Cpptools extension enables markdown in their hover info. See [Markdown comment support for tooltip display of hover #6020](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6020). The fix is available in [the 1.17.0 release](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/releases/tag/v1.17.0), [with some additional fixes in 1.17.2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6020#issuecomment-1678245913). There are some known issues (not very surprising, given that it's a new feature). Ex. [Some characters rendered incorrectly in Markdown comments when inline/block code is used
#11322](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/11322).

Related: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Hover. I did a quick test with the JavaScript extension, and assuming that uses this API, VS Code supports [the GitHub markdown tables extension](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-) (or something like it). That's the same markup syntax implemented here on Stack Exchange.

List example with Markdown (see also [the docs](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#list-items)):

```
- foo
- bar
- baz
```

Table example with Markdown:

```
| hello | goodbye |
|:-----:|:-------:|
| hi    | bye     |
```