# vscode - interpret HTML tags in Doxygen comments in such a way that, when displaying the documentation for the method, it properly renders the HTML

Tags: visual-studio-code, doxygen

I have the following Doxygen-styled comment in an example C/C++ function in vscode.

How to make the tool to interpret HTML tags within the Doxygen-style comment in such a way that, when displaying the documentation for the method within vscode itself, it properly renders the HTML part?

```
/*!
 * \brief Multiply two integers
 *
 * \example <code> int x = myFunc(5,7); </code>
 *
 * \param x first argument
 * \param y second argument
 *
 * \note An example of notes.<br/>. A list is as follows:
 * <ul>
 *  <li>First element</li>
 *  <li>Second element</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * \return the product of x and y
 */
int myFunc(int x, int y)
{
    return x * y;
}
```

P.S.: Use markdown instead of HTML is not an option.

The comment above resulted in the following. As observed, it did not parsed correctly the HTML parts of the comment.

[image]

Comment: are you using any doxygen-related extensions? if so, add a link to their marketplace pages please. If you're not, then see https://stackoverflow.com/q/76125672/11107541

Comment: No,  @user I am not (the only extension I have is C/C++ extension from Microsoft). And yes, it seems that basically they don't provide support for HTML nor Markdown when previewing Doxygen-styled comments in tooltips. I myself asked in the discussion of the issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6020. Seems that they will solve soon for Markdown but for the use of HTML tags within Markdown language seems not clear.