# VSCode Doxygen does not render Markdown

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Basically, some keywords & any markdown just display as normal text.

Example:

````c
/// @param test This works
/// ```c
///   example(3); // this does not
/// ```
/// other things like @b bold text also don't work
void example(int test) {};
````

Hint:
[Documentation when hovering over the function name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cab3L.png)

Is there anything I can do to enable Markdown in `VSCode`? I'm `kinda` new to `VSCode`, so when I tried to find something in settings, I didn't find anything related.

Additionally, I use `cpptools` for the hint display if that helps.

Comment: are you using any doxygen extensions that provide enhanced hover info? I'm not aware of any, but I'm curious if you are and are using one. Because otherwise, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/76125733/11107541